# Python 3.9 SQL Server connection - @ symbol beginning of password

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'm having an issue where the password of this DB contains an `@` at the beginning of the string. SQLAlchemy is throwing an error (below). I've had no issues when the `@` is in the middle of the string.

Also, this seems to be a python 3.9 thing. This same code works in a Python 3.6 environment.

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
import pymssql
import os
import urllib
import pandas as pd

engine = sql.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + user + ':' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)
                           + '@' + host + f'/{db}')

query = 'select * from metadata.lol'
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

error msg

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20017, b'DB-Lib error message 20017, severity 9:\nUnexpected EOF from the server (server.server.net)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (server.server.net)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (server.server.net)\n')`

Anyone run in to this/know a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to avoid issues like this is to get SQLAlchemy to build the connection URL for you:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pymssql",
    username=user,
    password=password,
    host=host,
    database=db
)
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

It will automatically take care of escaping any special characters that may be involved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution didn't fix the issue for us unfortunately. I got a similar error

Comment: I'm not sure if that means the issue is somewhere upstream